# Create a GREP style that finds paragraphs that starts with 2 possible words, then styles the entire paragraph

Tags: adobe-indesign, paragraph-styles

I have a QA style article where a question is posed, then answered.

```
Community News: How are you today?
Tom: I'm doing great!
CN: I'm doing well today. Thanks for asking.
```

I'd like to apply a grep style to each of the interviewers questions, but I haven't figured out how to apply the style to the entire paragraph.

The below grep finds the specific words and applies the style, but nothing I've tried applies the style to the entire paragraph

```
^(Community|CN:)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it shortly after I posted the question. Here's the GREP

```
^(Community.+?\r|CN:.+?\r)
```